# jquery.validate pwcheck password not work

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I used `jquery.validate`, I want to validate for the password when the user enters but it does not work.

Checking pwcheck password does not work. Please see what was wrong with me?

```
if (jQuery().validate) {
  $.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value) // consists of only these
      &&
      /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
      &&
      /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
  });

  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      forename: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 300
      },
      surname: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 300
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 300
      },
      password_repeat: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 300,
        equalTo: '#password'
      }
    },
    messages: {
      password: {
        pwcheck: "Das Passwort entspricht nicht den Kriterien!",
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
        form.submit();
      } else {
        alert('Please complete the reCaptcha to proceed');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You created the new rule called `pwcheck`, but you're not using it anyplace.

Comment: I solved my problem. Reason because i did not add `pwcheck: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

add `equalTo: "#password",` on the top instead of bottom.

```
password: {
   required: true,
   pwcheck: true,
   minlength: 8,
   maxlength: 300
},
password_repeat: {
   equalTo: "#password",
   required: true,
   minlength: 8,
   maxlength: 300,
}
```

Add it here:

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$/
```

However, it's much easier to do this without a lookahead:

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
   return /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$/.test(value) // consists of only these
       && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
       && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
});
```

Comment: I want to validate password when entering, the user must enter contains lowercase, capital letters, special characters, length> 8

Comment: It worked, but I only entered 8 characters and added 1 lowercase was valid?
 
I want to validate password when entering, the user must enter contains lowercase, capital letters, special characters, length> 8

Comment: use this `(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)
`

Comment: OK, but I want the user to enter the password must include special characters (eg: @ # $% ^! & *), I'm not good regex :)

Comment: Use this: `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$` and validate here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please correct your answer, then I will accept your answer. For later maybe someone will encounter the same error as me. :)

Comment: This Expression does not work, if you do a underscore _ as only special character
Try e.g.  testTEST_1